# Errors when running command "npx react-native run-android"

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-cli

C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\react-native-cli>cd AwesomeProject

C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\react-native-cli\AwesomeProject>npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED
> Error 'C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\react-native-cli\AwesomeProject\android\app\build\outputs\logs\manifest-merger-debug-report.txt (Access is denied)' while writing the merger report file, build can continue but merging activities will not be documented

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
12 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 10 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\react-native-cli\AwesomeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\manifest_merge_blame_file\debug\manifest-merger-blame-debug-report.txt (Access is denied)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 34s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081